# java android send Serializable data object to USB

Tags: java, android, serialization, usb, packet

I have a serializable data object that I want to send as packets thru USB.  It will have to be sent in 64 byte packets.  In C I would set a pointer to my object and send byte by byte for the sizeof the object.  I can't find a "sizeof" capability in java?  I have a 64 byte buffer that I can already send a packet of data with.  How can I load portions of fdata into my usb buffer?

```
FileDataFormat fdata;

public class FileDataFormat implements Serializable {

    public static final Integer numofswitches = 8;  //use 1-7
    // set for 10 channels for future
    byte switchesEnabled = 0; //switchesEnabled


    String[][] switch_name = new String[numofswitches][20];  //auxLabels's
    int[] configurableMaxCurrentTenths = new int[numofswitches];                    //configurableMaxCurrentTenths
    byte softStartByte = 0;         //softStartByte
    byte delayedButtonPressEnable = 0;      //delayedButtonPressEnable
    byte[] delayedButtonPressTimeDelayTenths = new byte[numofswitches];         
    byte currentReadingSelectedChannels = 0;
    byte threshholdEnabled = 0; //threshholdEnabled
    byte[] triggerChannel = new byte[numofswitches]; //triggerChannel
    boolean[] expressionType = new boolean[numofswitches]; //expression type > or <
    float[] hysteresis = new float[numofswitches];
    float[] threshhold = new float[numofswitches];

    public FileDataFormat() {

    }
}
```